# How to install a zip file in the local maven repository using gradle

Tags: gradle

I am trying to convert a couple of maven projects into using gradle.

In this maven project, there are some configuration files shared by all projects. These configuration files are packed into a zip and then installed into the local maven repository using the maven assembly plugin.

I managed to create a zip file using gradle with:

```
apply plugin: 'base'
apply plugin: 'maven'

group = 'my.test.config'

task dist(type: Zip) {
  classifier = 'config'
  from 'src'
}

assemble.dependsOn(dist)

artifacts {
  archives dist
}
```

but there is no install task created automatically. How do you tell the maven plugin it should create the install task and add the zip to this task?

I want to do `gradle install` and then the created zip file is installed into the local maven repository where it can be used by other (maven and/or gradle) projects as a build dependency.

(or is there a better way to make files available to multiple projects build by gradle without resorting to a static location on the filesystem or webserver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an `install` task, you'll have to apply both the `maven` and `java` plugins. Alternatively, it should also be possible to declare a task of type `Upload` and add a `mavenInstaller` repository as shown in the [Gradle User Guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#customizeInstaller).

Comment: Ok, but with `java` plugin, it tries to compile java sources which are not there (it does nothing but it look weird) I'll try the Upload type task.

Comment: @Peter, I'm using your suggested approach of using java plugin and it works nicely, except that I'm still getting a jar file in addition to the zip in my local repository. Is there any way to prevent the jar file from being generated/uploaded?